# How to deselect a list item in Sharepoint web part connection?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, connection

I have established a connection between two list web parts. In web part A, users are able to select a particular list item, and the list items in web part B will be filtered according to the value passed by web part A.
The question is, in the list web part A, can we allow users to deselect a item without selecting another item. That is, can user deselect an item and so no items will be selected in the web part?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation with connected Web Parts.  As far as I can tell there is no way to unselect once a selection is made the first time.  What I ended up doing was creating an item in the list I was using to make the selections that was called *Reset Filter*.  The * puts this at the top of the list and so it is always the first one selected.
Not a pretty solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be more clear on when you say deselect an item! when selecting is it a radio button for filtering? or checkboxes?

you should read up on this: the main part is:

> To enable the clearing of a filter so that users can see all the
>   values in the List View Web Part, select Allow Multiple selections. In
>   this case, the Select Filter Value(s) dialog box displays check boxes,
>   rather than radio buttons.
>
> Note   You cannot use this feature to display the filtered results of
>   two or more selections, because The List View Web Part does not
>   support multiple selections. If a user chooses multiple selections,
>   only the first selection is used.

you need to find the advanced filter options:

> If you selected the Allow Multiple selections property, to redisplay
>   all the values in the List View Web Part, the user must clear all the
>   check boxes in the Select Filter Value(s) dialog box, and then click
>   OK.

in your case deselecting will/should show no results as there is nothing selected!

look under **Connect a SharePoint List Filter Web Part to a List View Web Part**
you should be able to connect your list (a) by using SharePoint List Filter Web Part to connect to list (b) that is filtered with custom items ;)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-HA010250989.aspx